# How to select different assets files as my language change using Locale and Configuration?

Tags: android, configuration, locale, assets

I want to change **JSON file from assets folder** as per language change in my application and want to feel data in `RecyclerView`.

But my adapter do not apply that changes.

Comment: show what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have to set adapter again after selecting another locale file. If you are using RecyclerView, then set LayoutManager to your recycler view like this:

```
RecyclerView yourRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.yourRecyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
rc_qList.setHasFixedSize(true);
rc_qList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

RecyclerViewAdapter yourAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter (MainActivity.this, yourArrayList);
rc_qList.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current language of the device using the [`Locale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) object and then compare it to the constants of the `Locale` object. For example:

```
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+Locale.ENGLISH);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry());
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
```

prints:

```
onCreate: en
onCreate: English
onCreate: United Kingdom
onCreate: GB
onCreate: en
```

Don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after your data collection has changed to make sure the adapter applies the changes.